# Best format to store audio

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding

I've got an app that enables end-users to upload their audio files. Mostly songs/music. Currently, I am using Zencoder for my encoding service, which allows .mp3, .m4a, .mp4 or .ogg

When a user uploads an audio file, it will be available for other users to listen too via the app as well. Would the mp3 format be suitable enough for this?

Comment: Are other users able to download the music or is it just available through the app?

Comment: Well artists can have the option of making their music downloadable. Either way, other users can stream it, to listen. Are there any implications whether it is downloadable or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The licensing should be a major concern here.  mp3 has some interesting licensing conditions based on whether your service is free to the end-user.  Too complicated to go into length here, you can look it up on the web or contact Frauenhofer for more details.

The second obvious concern is bandwidth and audio quality.  The sampling has to be high enough that the end-user cannot tell the audio has been limited or compressed, but the file still needs to be small enough that the file can be downloaded or streamed quickly.  Any broadband connection these days can handle a 320kbps mp3 fairly easily.

Hopefully this will give you some good starting points for research:
[wikipedia:Comparison_of_audio_formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_audio_formats)

Comment: We assume the users uploading their audio files, have agreed to the terms and conditions, which basically states that before they can upload to our server, they must be the owner/artist of the audio file/song. Is this what you mean by "licensing conditions"?

Comment: Specifically by licensing I was referring to the right to decode the audio format into playable audio.  Many audio codecs are not free, and if the app makes the songs available for listening you may be obligated to obtain a license for the audio format (mp3, m4a, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

mp3 would suffice, mp4 would be better as it offers improved sound quality and compression over mp3.  Ogg is a good format but has less broad support on players.

To state the obvious, the quality of the sound is very much dependent on the original file uploaded by the user.  You will never improve on that quality, and each time you transcode between formats, you will degrade the quality.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask people to compare between mp3, AAC (m4a, mp4) and ogg - they will give you different answers. Different codecs with different bit rates produce different audio print. Some claim that for certain specific music types you should prefer one format over another.

You can google different bit rates and comparisons easily - technical part is easy.

I would go for ogg. Here's why:

1) It's easily good enough for the job

2) It's an Open Source

3) You don't get into trouble (legally) using it together with upload encodings.